# (Yii2) How would you render a yii\web\Response into a yii\widgets\ListView?

Tags: yii2, widget, response

I have no idea how to do this. I'm used to just query models and push the returned dataprovider to the widget. In this case I want to push an HTTP response.

```
Http-Code: 200 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, x-requested-with Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Max-Age: 600 Content-Disposition: inline Content-Type: application/json Date: Sun, 29 Jan 2017 17:00:45 GMT Server: nginx Content-Length: 101 Connection: Close { "id": "<20170129170045.88816.89784.A86FC8C8@example.com>", "message": "Queued. Thank you." }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear  to  me,  .. what kind of content you have in your response ..  update your question and add your related  controller/action code ..  and add the format/sample of your response too

Comment: On a second thought, I realize my question was pretty vague. Sorry for that. With HTTP Response I meant the return value from yii\httpclient\Client::send(); Would you still require me the response example?

Comment: depend  of the content of the response  .. update  your question and a sample of the content